# $.post not posting properly

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have this function which performs an ajax POST:

```
function consultaruserID(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

var userID = document.getElementById('userID').value;
var captcha = document.getElementById('captcha').value;
var token = encodeURIComponent(cToken);
    var params = "userID="+userID + "&captcha="+captcha + "&token="+token;


    xmlhttp.open('POST','/sys/getdata.php',false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.send(params);


    alert (xmlhttp.responseText);

}
```

Note that the string **token** is about 2000 in length and involves some special chars. Hence I used **encodeURIComponent(cToken);**

getdata.php process all the data and return a string. Works 100%.

Now, using the code below returns SUCCESS after posting but it won't bring me the string expected from getdata.php.

```
$.post("/sys/getdata.php",
    {userID: $('#userID').val(),
     captcha: $('#captcha').val(),
     token: encodeURIComponent(cToken)
    },
    function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }
);
```

On getdata.php I debugged the $_POST coming from the ajax of both methods. Both methods seems to be posting it properly. However the fucntion (which isn't mine) that proccess the **token** is somehow rejecting it from ajax.

Am I missing something here?

Sample of cToken:

```
var cToken='RadStyleSheetManager1_TSSM=&RadScriptManager1_TSM=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a33363de7-7c08-435e-ab35-682b2ed2c688%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a4701e229-f1c8-4ec4-9c40-b2d233d95d5d%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a22a6274a%3aed16cbdc%3a11e117d7&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKLTc1OTk5NDIwOA8WAh4IcHJldkdVSUQFJDlkYWRiODRjLWYyN2YtNDA2Yi04MjE4LWM3MGI4NzY4MmI1NxYCAgMPZBYCAgUPFCsAAw8WBh4FV2lkdGgbAAAAAADAckABAAAAHgZIZWlnaHQbAAAAAADAUkABAAAAHgRfIVNCAoADZBYCHgtDdXJyZW50R3VpZAUkOWRhZGI4NGMtZjI3Zi00MDZiLTgyMTgtYzcwYjg3NjgyYjU3FCsAA2RkFgIeCk1pblRpbWVvdXQCAxYCAgEPZBYIZg9kFgJmD2QWBmYPDxYKHwIbAAAAAAAASUABAAAAHwEbAAAAAACAZkABAAAAHghDc3NDbGFzc2UeCEltYWdlVXJsBVN%2BL1RlbGVyaWsuV2ViLlVJLldlYlJlc291cmNlLmF4ZD90eXBlPXJjYSZndWlkPTlkYWRiODRjLWYyN2YtNDA2Yi04MjE4LWM3MGI4NzY4MmI1Nx8DAoIDZGQCAQ8PFgIeBFRleHQFEUdlcmFyIG5vdmEgaW1hZ2VtZGQCAg8WBB4JaW5uZXJodG1sBQVPdXZpch4EaHJlZgVXfi9UZWxlcmlrLldlYi5VSS5XZWJSZXNvdXJjZS5heGQ%2FdHlwZT1jYWgmYW1wO2d1aWQ9OWRhZGI4NGMtZjI3Zi00MDZiLTgyMTgtYzcwYjg3NjgyYjU3ZAIBDw8WCh8CGwAAAAAAAElAAQAAAB8BGwAAAAAAgGZAAQAAAB8GZR8HBVN%2BL1RlbGVyaWsuV2ViLlVJLldlYlJlc291cmNlLmF4ZD90eXBlPXJjYSZndWlkPTlkYWRiODRjLWYyN2YtNDA2Yi04MjE4LWM3MGI4NzY4MmI1Nx8DAoIDZGQCAg8WBh8JBQVPdXZpch8KBVd%2BL1RlbGVyaWsuV2ViLlVJLldlYlJlc291cmNlLmF4ZD90eXBlPWNhaCZhbXA7Z3VpZD05ZGFkYjg0Yy1mMjdmLTQwNmItODIxOC1jNzBiODc2ODJiNTceB1Zpc2libGVnZAIDD2QWBGYPDxYIHwZlHglBY2Nlc3NLZXllHghUYWJJbmRleAEAAB8DAgJkZAIBDw8WBh8GZR8IBRxUeXBlIHRoZSBjb2RlIGZyb20gdGhlIGltYWdlHwMCAmRkGAIFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBQtSYWRDYXB0Y2hhMQULUmFkQ2FwdGNoYTEPFCsAAgUkOWRhZGI4NGMtZjI3Zi00MDZiLTgyMTgtYzcwYjg3NjgyYjU3BgAAAAAAAAAAZC71hndqclnXtz26igXAh8hMTN8v1xbnYlEz5BpnTD2e&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWAgKQq574CQLYv5ykDAZWk768pXDUic2zwz0szJjtC6%2ByEIHnfkVFizDz0zTL&RadCaptcha1_ClientState=&RadCaptcha1%24CaptchaTextBox=';
```

Comment: Hi, @AZevedo...Where is 'cToken' being declared/populated, and what is its value?

Comment: Hi! I'm posting it on the topic. It is declared inside the HTML HEADER.

Comment: You shouldn't URI encode `cToken`.  jQuery will automatically apply URI encoding when it converts your object literal into a query string. When you say "token is somehow rejecting it from ajax", what does this mean? Are you able to make the post?  Are you getting a non-200 response to your post from the server script? Where is the problem actually happening?

Comment: @MikeBrant Thanks! you got it! I took away URI encode from ajax and it worked! I suppose it was 'double' encoding it.

Comment: @Azevedo Exactly. I will add as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't URI encode `cToken`. jQuery will automatically apply URI encoding when it converts your object literal into a query string.

Answer (score 0):

Your token seems to contain extra parameters which are not being passed correctly, try the passing the data string:

```
var userID = document.getElementById('userID').value;
var captcha = document.getElementById('captcha').value;
var token = encodeURIComponent(cToken);
var params = "userID="+userID + "&captcha="+captcha + "&token="+token;

$.post("/sys/getdata.php",
    params,
    function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }
);
```